# Can't open the django project index page in a browser side in EC2 AWS

Tags: django, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server

**Problem:**
I can't:
1)use a local browser to open `http://<public IP>:8000`
2)use terminal to `curl -v http://<public IP>:8000`
3)Ping

I can:
1)use terminal to run `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000`, the result indicates the django server is working.

**Background:**
I'm working on a MacOS. Python 3.9.13,Django 4.1.7, MySQL 8.0.31.
I setup my django project in my EC2 server, also setup a RDS which is working now.
Today, I try to open the project's index page via my browser, but there is no response.

So I checked inbound rules:

```
1)All traffic :0.0.0.0/0
2)Custom TCP :port: 8000, 0.0.0.0/0
3)Custom TCP :port: 8000, 172.31.0.0/20  (subnet, IPv4 CIDR)
4)Custom TCP :port: 8000, 172.31.16.0/20    (subnet, IPv4 CIDR)
5)Custom TCP :port: 8000, 172.31.32.0/20    (subnet, IPv4 CIDR)
6)Custom ICMP:echo request, 0.0.0.0/0
7)All TCP : My IP, x.x.x.x/32
8)SSH: port 22, 0.0.0.0/0
```

Also I set
1)public IP in the settings.py
`ALLOW_HOSTS = ['public IP', '127.0.0.1'] (no port)`

2)firewall allows 8000 port
`sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=8000/tcp --permanent`

Finally, I run django server `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

**Result:**
1)`curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000`,

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8000...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> GET /login/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.88.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 22 Mar 2023 11:43:26 GMT
< Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.9.13
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Vary: Cookie
< Content-Length: 10761
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Referrer-Policy: same-origin
< Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
< Set-Cookie:  csrftoken="xxxx-I remove this token"; expires=Wed, 20 Mar 2024 11:43:26 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
< 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
end...
```

2)`curl -v http://<public IP>:8000`
`curl: Failed to connect to <public IP> port 8000 after 130052 ms: Couldn't connect to server`

When I remove '127.0.0.1' from the settings.py, the `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000` is also not working.
So I set ALLOW_HOSTS = ['*'], the `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000` is working ,but in terms of the the `curl -v <public IP>:8000` is still not working.

That's my problem.
Your help will be VERY APPRECIATED!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a security group rule to allow traffic on port 8000 from your router's IP address.

Also, make sure you have internet gateway in place to allow connections from the outside world into the EC2.

Comment: Very appreciated. But there's no help though.

I add router IP to "inbound rule", and I also checked ACLs, firewall. But still it does not work.

Comment: AWS Internet Gateway is like the router of your VPC and without it, there is no access into the VPC and the EC2, even when public IP was attached to the EC2. Reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, thx to the author:[Start Django development server on AWS EC2 Amazon Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68183866/start-django-development-server-on-aws-ec2-amazon-linux?rq=1)

I first test `curl http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.region.compute.amazonaws.com:8000`, and it's working, and then I changed the security group and add it.